# SQL: Number of occurrences as a percentage of only certain values

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2012

I am trying to look at the proportions of organisations located either in a rural or urban location - the category 'Rurality' has either 'Rural', 'Urban' or 'NULL'. I can calculate the percentages of 'Urban' and 'Rural' as a percentage of all values, but I want to exclude all occurrences with a 'NULL' value.

At the moment I have:

```
SELECT Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped as 'Type',
COUNT(*) as 'Count',
(COUNT(Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [SWFC_Project].[dbo].[Lookup_SchoolLevelIndicators])) AS Perc 
FROM [SWFC_Project].[dbo].[Lookup_SchoolLevelIndicators] 
WHERE Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped]
ORDER BY 'Count' desc, Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped
```

And my output is:

```
Type | Count | Perc
-------------------
Urban| 78117 | 72
Rural| 27693 | 25
```

However the percentages only add up to 97%, whereas I want 'Urban' and 'Rural' to my 100%, excluding 'NULL' values.

I'm using SSMS if that makes any difference.

Comment: Does `* 100.0` make any difference?

Comment: You have no WHERE IS NOT NULL in your subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your subquery you must add the condition on IS NOT NULL like this:

```
SELECT Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped as 'Type',
COUNT(*) as 'Count',
(COUNT(Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped)* 100 / 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM [SWFC_Project].[dbo].[Lookup_SchoolLevelIndicators]
WHERE Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped IS NOT NULL) AS Perc 
FROM [SWFC_Project].[dbo].[Lookup_SchoolLevelIndicators] 
WHERE Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped]
ORDER BY 'Count' desc, Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply switch to `COUNT(Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped)` instead of `COUNT(*)`, which excludes NULLs.

But SQL Server supports Windowed Aggregate Function, you just need a *GROUP SUM*:

```
SELECT Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped AS 'Type',
   COUNT(Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped) AS 'Count',

   100 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Perc 
FROM [SWFC_Project].[dbo].[Lookup_SchoolLevelIndicators] 
WHERE Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY [Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped]
ORDER BY 'Count' DESC, Geography_Rurality_DEFRA_Grouped
```